# Differential equation- Solutions to initial condition problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

The equation given is 
$$x(t)=C_{1}e^{-t}+C_{2}e^{2t}$$
$$x^{''}-x^{'}-2x=0$$
The first and second derivatives are given respectfully
$$-C_{1}e^{-t}+2C_{2}e^{2t}$$
$$C_{1}e^{-t}+4C_{2}e^{2t}$$
I have verified that the problem does in fact equal zero.
The given conditions are:
$$x(0)=10$$
$$x^{'}(0)=8$$
After substitution and evaluation of the original and first prime equations I got $C_2=\frac{8}{3}$ and $C_1=\frac{16}{3}$
and having no one around to check if I'm correct,I was hoping that someone could tell me if I'm right or if I made a small mistake.

Comment: when you sum both coefficiencts you don't get 10

Comment: $x(0)=C_1+C_2$ and $x'(0)=-C_1+2C_2.$ With your answers, you have $C_1+C_2=8$ and $-C_1+2C_2=0.$ So this answer is wrong. It looks like you should get $C_1=4, C_2=6.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{cases}
c_1+c_2=10 \\
-c_1+2c_2=8 \\
\end{cases}
$$
As Thomas commented 
the sum of the two equations gives:
$$3c_2=18 \implies c_2=6$$
and
$$c_1=10-c_2=4$$
You made a mistake somewhere. Can you post your solution ? So we can check it ?

Comment: Slightly easier, just add the first two equations to get $3c_2=18.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes completely right Thomas